# Understanding python syntax - variable followed by parenthesis

Tags: python, syntax, semantics

I saw this syntax in the python implementation of bitcoin over here.

https://github.com/samrushing/caesure/blob/master/caesure/bitcoin.py

I have never seen this syntax before, can someone explain it to me or show me somewhere in the documentation where I can understand it?

```
    def dump (self, fout=sys.stdout):
        D = fout.write
        D ('hash: %s\n' % (hexify (dhash (self.render())),))
        D ('inputs: %d\n' % (len(self.inputs)))
        for i in range (len (self.inputs)):
            (outpoint, index), script, sequence = self.inputs[i]
            try:
                redeem = pprint_script (parse_script (script))
            except ScriptError:
                redeem = script.encode ('hex')
            D ('%3d %064x:%d %r %d\n' % (i, outpoint, index, redeem, sequence))
        D ('outputs: %d\n' % (len(self.outputs),))
        for i in range (len (self.outputs)):
            value, pk_script = self.outputs[i]
            pk_script = pprint_script (parse_script (pk_script))
            D ('%3d %s %r\n' % (i, bcrepr (value), pk_script))
        D ('lock_time: %s\n' % (self.lock_time,))
```

I'm talking about `D ('hash: %s\n' % (hexify (dhash (self.render())),))`

There are many lines where there is a variable followed by a parenthesis. I don't understand what it does.

Comment: Can you clarify what you find odd about this? It's a function call, just like ``hexify``, ``dhash``, ``self.render``, ``len``, ``range`` and many others in that code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can assign functions to variables.

`fout.write` is a function, so in this example, `D` is assigned to that function.

`D = fout.write`

In this line
`D ('hash: %s\n' % (hexify (dhash (self.render())),))`, you are calling the function `D`, that is, `fout.write`. It would be the same as:

`fout.write('hash: %s\n' % (hexify (dhash (self.render())),))`

Answer (score 2):

You can have a variable that has function type.

Maybe this other example is easier to understand:

```
foo = print
foo("Hello") # This prints Hello in the terminal
```

You can see there is a special class for this kind of variables:

```
>>> type(foo)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

The same happens with your defined functions:

```
def hello(s):
    print(s)

hello("123") # prints 123

bar = hello
bar("123") # prints 123
```

In this case, the class type is different:

```sh
>>> type(bar)
<class 'function'>
```